# Determining all complex Z in the equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $n \in \mathbb N$.  Determine all complex numbers $z \in \mathbb C $ such that $ |z| ^{n-2} = 1.$
How would i begin this question, thanks!

Comment: If a positive number $r$ is such that $r^{n-2} = 1$, what can you say about $r$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r=|z|$ then notice that $r$ is a nonnegative real number.

$r^{n-2}=1$ if $n=2$ then it is true for all $r>0\implies $ it is true for all $z\neq 0$

if $n\ne2$ then $r=1\implies$ it is true for all $z=xi+y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: How would i state what the final answer would be?

Comment: @user136088: it is the final answer, it has infinitly many roots in both case. what do yo know about $n$? in your question, it can be anynumber.

Comment: Yeah the question doesn't say anything about n. Thus for this equation, there are infinitely many roots right?

Comment: Oh wait, i missed the part where it said n is a natural number. How would this affect the answer?

Comment: @user136088: in our case, it does not change anything.

Comment: @user136088 it doesn't matter, it's the absolute value that causes the entire unit circle to be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $n = 2$, then $\vert z \vert = 1$ for *all* $z \ne 0$, and perhaps also for $z = 0$, depending on how one looks at $0^0$.  In any event, the case $n =2$ stands by itself, especially in light of the fact that $\vert z \vert^{n -2} = 1$ implies $\vert z \vert = 1$ for $n \ne 2$; then any unimodular $z$ is a solution, and only such $z$ are solutions.  Thus $z = e^{i \theta}$ for *any* real $\theta$; of course, since $e^{i(\theta + 2\pi)} = e^{i \theta}$, we only need consider $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$; such $\theta$ yield all solutions to $\vert z \vert^{n - 2} = 1$ when $n \ne 2$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always, *Fiat Lux!!!***